# How to use the word "draped" and "wrapped"?

Tags: word-usage

Should I say that she "draped over the towel on her hair" or " draped on the towel on her hairs"? or should I use wrapped instead of draped?

Comment: *Drape* implies the towel is simply *lying on her head*, with no structure: lifeless. Since that is not how women wear a towel when they are drying their hair, you want to say *wrapped*. However, the towel isn't typically wrapped around her *hair* (soley), per se; it's *wrapped around her head*, so you probably want to say that (which is how it is most commonly and idiomatically described). Also important: it's *hair* (mass) not *hairs* (plural). If that seems weird to you, you might also like to check out our sister site, [ELL.se].

Comment: @DanBron -not weird ,but helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**drape** means thing is covered, but not encircled; the cloth that is draped does not  go *under* the thing being covered.

http://pozasalon.com/images/uploads/towel_dry_hair_no_rub.JPG

**wrap** means to surround completely

So if she did not enclose all her hair in the towel, she **draped** the towel *over* (or *on*) her hair.

If she got virtually all of her hair inside the towel, so you couldn't see it (as in a *turban*, 
http://www.google.com/search?q=hair+towel+turban&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&hl=en
then you'd say she **wrapped** her hair.

However, your syntax is wrong.

- She draped **the towel over her hair.**

  Or
- She wrapped **the towel around her hair.** (or She wrapped up her hair in a towel.)

As used here,  "hair" is a *mass noun* ; we do not use plural to mean all of one's hair.